# How to display the exact columns that contain a specific value within that row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a pandas `df` that contains a bunch of 0's and 1's.

and I already have a specific row that I want

[image]

I want to display the columns of that row that has a value of 1. Like how `home_team_Belgium` has a `1` value.

I want it to look like:

```
row#  home_team_Belgium  home_team_something
29            1                  1
```

What commands can I use?

Comment: df[df.home_team_Belgium==1]

Comment: @skrubber that only displays Belgium. What about the columns that have 1's that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
row = df.loc[29]
row = row[row == 1]
row = row.to_frame().T
row.columns.name = 'row#'
print(row)
```

In general, if you want to iterate over all rows and print out the columns contains 1 in each row:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(3, 5)), columns=list('abcde'))
# To iterate over all rows. You can also select specific rows with `index`
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # To select target cols you want in each row.
    output = row[row == 1]
    # To print each result row horizontally.
    output = output.to_frame().T
    # Make header row exactly in your expected format.
    output.columns.name = 'row#'
    print(output, end='\n\n')
```

---

Random DataFrame input:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  0  0  1  1
1  0  0  1  0  0
2  0  1  0  0  0
```

Printed output:

```
row#  a  d  e
0     1  1  1

row#  c
1     1

row#  b
2     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
r = df[df.index == 29]
cols_to_keep = r.iloc[0].astype(bool).tolist()
r.iloc[:, cols_to_keep]
```